# SBT not running from root directory

Tags: docker, scala, ubuntu, dockerfile, sbt

```
FROM openjdk:8 as build
ENV SBT_VERSION "1.5.8"
ENV APP_HOME /service
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install apt-transport-https curl gnupg -yqq && \
  echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list && \
  echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list && \
  curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg --import && \
  chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt=$SBT_VERSION && \
  sbt sbtVersion
```

I'm getting an error saying E: Version '1.5.8' for 'sbt' was not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change my work directory away from default `/` to get this to work. Try below (`WORKDIR` changes folder, `cd` in the commands likely have the same effect) could. This builds and runs with `sbt` command for me.

```
FROM openjdk:8 as build
ENV SBT_VERSION "1.5.8"
ENV APP_HOME /service
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install apt-transport-https curl gnupg -yqq && \
  echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list && \
  echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list && \
  curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg --import && \
  chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt=$SBT_VERSION && \
  sbt sbtVersion
```

```
root@a94ff4797239:/service# sbt
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.8 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_312)
[info] loading project definition from /service/project
[info] set current project to service (in build file:/service/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///root/.sbt/1.0/server/c75bcef1d951ec508da8/sock
[info] started sbt server
sbt:service>
```