# cannot run sbt from root directory

Tags: docker, scala, dockerfile, sbt

I'm getting an error as follows:

```
#8 46.51 [error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot run sbt from root directory without -Dsbt.rootdir=true; see sbt/sbt#1458
#8 46.51 [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

The Dockerfile is mostly just downloading and installing the debian. But something is making sbt unhappy. Not sure what it is.

```
FROM openjdk:8 as build
ENV SBT_VERSION "1.5.8"
ENV APP_HOME /service
# Install sbt
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to run **sbt** on a **Docker**? - Anyways, the error is pretty clear, don't run **sbt** in the root folder and less with a root user

Comment: Did you look at [the referenced sbt issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1458)?

Comment: Double Posted [What's wrong with this Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624946/whats-wrong-with-this-dockerfile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is using root aka `/` as the working directory. Adding `WORKDIR /home` before the `RUN ...` command fixes the `docker build ...` error and I was able to `docker run ...` successfully.

`docker build ...`

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.so -t 70625015:latest .   
[+] Building 69.4s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.so                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 387B                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:8                                                                        0.0s
 => [2/3] WORKDIR /home                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [3/3] RUN   curl -L -o sbt-1.5.8.deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian/sbt-1.5.8.deb &&   dpkg -i sbt-1.5  68.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                   0.9s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                  0.9s 
 => => writing image sha256:99e90196e9a6b2d768adf4e6a01883785847758a5f136f4a858a636e60b77819                             0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/70625015:latest                                                                       0.0s
```

`docker run ....` launching to an `sbt` console.

```
(:|✔)$ docker run -it 70625015:latest
root@3a1084220dc9:/home#
```

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the error your getting try adding before the `RUN` command

the end result will be

```
FROM openjdk:8 as build
ENV SBT_VERSION "1.5.8"
ENV APP_HOME /service
WORKDIR /app
# Install sbt
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion
```